# How to see image tag name in my private docker registry

Tags: docker

I can get my images info from docker registry like this:

 `curl https://tplink:tplink@registry.tp-link.net:8000/v1/search`

But there is no image_id or tag. I need tag name When I delete images from from private docker registry.

Answer (score 0):

From this command, (`curl`) you will get the list of docker images in name only.

Like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Accept
Content-Type: application/json

{"num_pages": 1,
  "num_results": 3,
  "results" : [
     {"name": "ubuntu", "description": "An ubuntu image..."},
     {"name": "centos", "description": "A centos image..."},
     {"name": "fedora", "description": "A fedora image..."}
   ],
  "page_size": 25,
  "query":"search_term",
  "page": 1
 }
```

Then you need to send extra GET command (docker registry API) to check those docker images one by one to get list of tags.

```
GET /v1/repositories/ubuntu/tags

[
{
    "layer": "fa81ed08",
    "name": "latest"
},
{
    "layer": "3db9c44f",
    "name": "10.04"
},
....
]
```

see https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/registry_api/ for detail.